# ESLint global vars included via <script> are causing undefined error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

My react app is bundled with WebPack and it uses global scripts (e.g. jQuery) that are included via  tags and are defined in WebPack externals.

But my ESLint configuration doesn't know about them and i get `'no-unded'` error in ESLint.

So how can i tell ESLint that those are not undefined vars, or should i change my WebPack config somehow?

Comment: Google eslint globals: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried adding globals in .eslintric.js config file

```
 module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "SomeVar": true
  },
};
```